# Using the beamer style Berlin

Tags: beamer

This package makes my beamer presentation go all blue with those dots at the top which tell you which section and subsection I am on, right?

Thing is, when I make my presentation, compile it and then preview it, all the dots at the top aren't in a neat order. For example, in section 1, they go horizontally. The in section 2 they go vertically, and now in section 3, there is some going horizontally and then like 1 dot vertically and then a few more horizontally.

How do I neaten this up?

Comment: Hi Kaish, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for folks to play with? Welcome! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the intended behavior. Horizontal dots show the number of individual frames in that subsection and vertical shows the number of subsections. Each vertical group is a section.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\subsection{AA}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\section{B}
\subsection{BA}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BB}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BC}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}


\section{C}
\subsection{CA}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\subsection{CB}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The navigation circles can also be combined onto one line instead of taking up a line per subsection by passing the option `compress` eg in `\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}` or `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`.