# Beamer Berlin theme: Navigation does not appear

Tags: beamer

I tried to follow the example from

[Using the beamer style Berlin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85237/using-the-beamer-style-berlin)

and have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

{
\usecolortheme{dolphin} % Beamer color theme
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\subsection{AA}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}

\section{B}
\subsection{BA}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BB}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\subsection{BC}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}


\section{C}
\subsection{CA}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\subsection{CB}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

But unfortunately the navigation header does not appear in white nor are the headers marked the same way as in the above mentioned link. Is it a local problem or does it appear the same way at others?

[image]

Comment: I have no problem with current TeXLive and running your example with `pdflatex`

Comment: Did you run your code at least twice?

Comment: yes, several times, but no difference :(

Comment: In your MWE the footer is empty because `\author`, `\data` etc. are not defined. But on running exactly your code, I get indeed a filled headline.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem not reproducable